# Slow site unless FPC is enabled

Tags: magento-1.9, database

We've got a Magento install that's currently running like a dog... We've had to install FPC to help with the site speed but this doesn't help with the search.

I've logged into the server and I can see the load of the server is really high and it's MySQL that's hogging it all.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Disable your FPC, then run the Magento profiler.

You're wanting to look at the 'time' column - the total of this column is your rendering time. So look for a line with a high value, this will give you the culprit.

Here's a guide that'll help you;
https://www.nublue.co.uk/blog/using-magento-profiler-to-speed-up-magento-performance/

Another way is to run it on your staging server, and disable all non-default modules then re-enable them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Disable fpc, then use a profiler (like tideways, blackfire, xdebug, ...) to look into the cause and fix it.

Mostly this is some bad written code.

Afterwards, you can enable FPC again.